# Cannot read property $socket of undefined - test socket.io

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, socket.io, jestjs, this

I'm using VueJS and socket.io to generate a message to display to all of the users of my application.
My message is emitted from my action of my store.
It's working well but when I test my code, I have an error: "cannot read property $socket of undefined" (comes from my action).

My main.js:

```
/*Socket*/
import io from 'socket.io-client'

if(window.location.hostname === 'localhost'){
    //Dev
    console.log('Dev')
    Vue.prototype.$socket = io(`http://localhost:3000`) 
}else{
    //Prod
    console.log('Prod')
    Vue.prototype.$socket = io.connect(window.location.hostname)
}

Vue.use(Vuelidate)
Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
Vue.use(BootstrapVueIcons)

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

My action of my store:

```
const addPick = function(context) {
    //console.log('actions - ADD PICK');
    let request_body = {
      game_id : context.state.selectedGame.id,
      player_id : context.state.pickedPlayer.id,
      user_id : context.state.user.id
    }
    axios.post(`api/add_picked_player`,request_body).then(response => {
      console.log(response.data);
      //Building of the message to display to the other players
      let object_to_emit = {};
      object_to_emit = {
        message : context.state.pickedPlayer.name + ' has been selected by '+context.state.user.username,
        game_id : context.state.selectedGame.id
      }
      this._vm.$socket.emit('player_added',object_to_emit);
      
      this.dispatch('getDraftList'); //to update the player available in the draft 
      this.dispatch('getUserListInGame'); //to update the user information in the game in the UserLineUp component
      context.commit('UpdateUserListInGame',context.state.userListInGame);
      this.dispatch('getPickedTeamByUser'); //to update the team picked of the user
    }).catch(error => console.log(error));
};
```

My test:

```
import io from 'socket.io-client'
/*Mocking of Socket io*/
let mockSocket = io('http://localhost:3000');
let message = "message to send";
jest.mock("socket.io-client", () => {
    const socket = {
      emit: jest.fn(() => { 
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
          resolve(true)
        })
      })
    }
  return jest.fn(() => socket);
})

describe('addPick', () => {
  test('Success: should add a player and update information (player available, user in the game, team picked by users) in the store', async () => {
    const context = {
      state: {
        selectedGame: {
          id:119
        },
        pickedPlayer: {
          id:1
        },
        user: {
          id:1
        },
        userListInGame: [
        {
          id:1
        },{
          id:19
        }
        ]
      },
      commit: jest.fn()
    }
    const response = {
      data: "the draft is not finished"
    };
    //const dispatch = jest.fn();

    axios.post.mockResolvedValue(response) //OR axios.post.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve(response));
    await actions.addPick(context)
    expect(axios.post).toHaveBeenCalledWith("api/add_picked_player",{
      "game_id" : context.state.selectedGame.id,
      "player_id" : context.state.pickedPlayer.id,
      "user_id":context.state.user.id
    });
    expect(axios.post).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2)
    //expect(context.commit).toHaveBeenCalledWith("UpdateUserListInGame", context.state.userListInGame)

    expect(io).toHaveBeenCalledWith(`http://localhost:3000`)
    expect(io).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    await mockSocket.emit("player_added",message)
    expect(mockSocket.emit).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    expect(mockSocket.emit).toHaveBeenCalledWith("player_added",message)
    //expect(context.commit).toHaveBeenCalledWith("UpdateUserListInGame", context.state.userListInGame)
  });
```

I mocked Axios and my axios request is called successfully.
Same for my emit function of io socket.
The test goes successfully for now but:

- I have the error message in my console.log of my action: "cannot read property $socket of undefined"
- When I try to test expect(context.commit).toHaveBeenCalledWith("UpdateUserListInGame", context.state.userListInGame), I have an error because of my socket io. This error is the context.commit is not called. (This test is successful without all the message emitted and my socket io part)

What is wrong?

1. The way I parameter my socket IO in my main.js ?
2. The way I call my emit() function ? Do I have another possibility of using "this._vm" instead?